# Playwright Error: waiting for expect(locator).toBeVisible()

Tags: typescript, playwright

When I run my test in Playwright the assertion always fails. It does not match the h2 element even though the page does display it.

My test code:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Thomann', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.thomann.de/intl/index.html');
  await page.locator('xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]').click();
  await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: 'Nuestras categorías' })).toBeVisible();
});
```

Log Error:

```
Error: Timed out 5000ms waiting for expect(locator).toBeVisible()

Locator: getByRole('heading', { name: 'Nuestras categorías' })
Expected: visible
Received: hidden
Call log:
  - expect.toBeVisible with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for getByRole('heading', { name: 'Nuestras categorías' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about you, but I'm redirected to https://www.thomannmusic.com/index.html. It could be because I'm in the USA. In any case, I suggest running headfully with `npx playwright test --headed` to make sure you're winding up in the right place.

Otherwise, the code works for me if I use English text:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test";

test("has an 'Our Categories' heading after redirect and cookie reject", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.thomann.de/intl/index.html");
  await expect(page).toHaveURL("https://www.thomannmusic.com/index.html");
  await page.getByRole("button", {name: "Reject Cookies"}).click();
  await expect(page.getByRole("heading", {name: "Our Categories"})).toBeVisible();
});
```

Notice I'm not using an xpath, which is discouraged because it's not [user-visible](https://playwright.dev/docs/best-practices#test-user-visible-behavior), and it's fragile, since if a single div changes in the chain, the path will no longer be valid.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the browser was loading the page in English so the text it shows is "Our Categories", I was looking for a way to run the graphical environment but I didn't know I've only been learning playwright for a couple of hours, thank you very much for your answer :D